# Custom project in Adobe Flex Builder 3?

Tags: apache-flex, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, flexbuilder

Is it possible to create a custom project type using Adobe Flex Builder 3?  I'd like to create my own custom project template that creates certain directories, sets Source Path and Library Path values, etc. so that I don't have to do it manually.

I'm using the standalone version of Flex Builder, which is running on Eclipse 3.3.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flex Builder 3 can't do anything like that :/.  I've created a set of custom generators in ruby, that work just the way Ruby on Rails generators work: Define a bunch of template files and directories, run a single command with project name and I get a new Flex project completely customized and ready to go.

What [Flex Builder 4 REALLY Should Include](http://blog.flashgen.com/2008/08/27/what-flex-builder-4-really-should-include/)...

Answer (score 0):

I just have a project 'template' that I create a copy of and import when I need it.
But I guess you could theoretically write a plugin but that's total overkill.